# Map two Domains to two endpoints hosted under single Server (in Cloudflare)

Tags: wordpress, dns, cloud, hosting, cloudflare

I have hosted two different Wordpress websites hosted under single cloud VPS. The two Wordpress instances are currently accessible using the format of URL as below,

http://30.24.32.545/example1.com/public_html

http://30.24.32.545/example2.com/public_html

I needs to map these two websites in Cloudflare to enable access these two websites with two different domain names.

http://example1.com -> http://30.24.32.545/example1.com/public_html

http://example2.com -> http://30.24.32.545/example2.com/public_html

Can someone help me to identify the best possible method to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably to configure something like NGINX or Apache on the server to take care of this. Then you can just point to the IP in Cloudflare for the same domains.

The NGINX config should look something like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example1.com;
   location / {

      proxy_pass http://localhost/public_html
   }
}
```